# How to put a Bottom Sheet above BottomNavBar

Tags: flutter, user-interface, user-experience

I was wondering how do you put a bottomsheet above the bottomnavbar, like for example the binance lite app as a case right here:
[example](https://makeagif.com/gif/-0FRHp0)

i tried using rootnavigator false but it didnt work because in my bottomnavbar, i got a logo and i want when i click on it, it pops up a modal but that logo from the bottomnavbar is still there.

Just using showbottommodalsheet doesnt work because it covers the bottomnavbar so the logo is not seen.
can u guys help me with a solution please?

this is my code for the bottomnavbar

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => 
                  showModalBottomSheet(context: context, 
                  useRootNavigator: false,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container();
                  })
                ,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 4, 0, 8),
                  child: Assets.images.logo.svg(),
                ),
              ),
              label: 'Buy', 
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can return a Column under the bottom sheet then use the bottom navbar and your bottom sheet item inside the column. this is the ideal solution.

Comment: i dont think i can return a bottomnavbar inside the bottom sheet

Comment: you can 100%. but you need a little bit of customization.  let me do  it for you.

Comment: it says exception has occured. GoError : The parent route must be a page route to have a GoRouterState

Comment: can you  please share the  error massage screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

first, create a widget for your bottom sheet it can be a separate dart file or inside a class. then put this code there:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class BottomSheetExample {
      late BuildContext context;
      BottomSheetExample(this.context,);
      Future<void> tripDetails() async {
        final body = StatefulBuilder(builder: (modalContext, modalSetState) {
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 400,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [Text('This Is BottomSheet')],
            ),
          );
        });
       return await showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context ,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              top: Radius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    child: body,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

OK, that's it. You have to  call

```
BottomSheetExample(context).tripDetails()
```

you can call this by the VoidCallBack method like this:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: ()=> BottomSheetExample(context).tripDetails(),
    child: const Padding(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
       child: Text('this is bottom sheet),
       )
     )
```

and The final result is this:

[image]

Hope it will solve your problem. let me know.